# Default parameters from cross dependency is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, circular-dependency, es6-modules

I have two files which co-depend on each other:

runner.js

```
import { build, altBuild } from './build';

const defaultValue = {
  code: 42,
};

export function options(value = defaultValue) {
  return value;
}

export function altOptions(value = { code: 9 }) {
  return value;
}

console.log(build());
console.log(altBuild());
```

build.js

```
import { options, altOptions } from './runner';

const buildParams = {
  foo: 'bar',
  extra: options(),
}

const altBuildParams = {
  foo: 'bar',
  extra: altOptions(),
}

export function build() {
  console.log(options());
  return buildParams;
}

export function altBuild() {
  console.log(altOptions());
  return altBuildParams;
}
```

When running I would expect the output to be:

```
{ code: 42 }
{ foo: 'bar', extra: { code: 42 } }
{ code: 9 }
{ foo: 'bar', extra: { code: 9 } }
```

But instead it is:

```
{ code: 42 }
{ foo: 'bar', extra: undefined }
{ code: 9 }
{ foo: 'bar', extra: { code: 9 } }
```

I can work around that, but I got really curious on why it's happening. I'm using Node 7.10, and babel-node 6.26 to run this example.

---

Update with the transpiled code:

transpiled runner.js

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.options = options;
exports.altOptions = altOptions;

var _build = require('./build');

var defaultValue = {
  code: 42
};

function options() {
  var value = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : defaultValue;

  return value;
}

function altOptions() {
  var value = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : { code: 9 };

  return value;
}

console.log((0, _build.build)());
console.log((0, _build.altBuild)());
```

transpiled build.js

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.build = build;
exports.altBuild = altBuild;

var _runner = require('./runner');

var buildParams = {
  foo: 'bar',
  extra: (0, _runner.options)()
};

var altBuildParams = {
  foo: 'bar',
  extra: (0, _runner.altOptions)()
};

function build() {
  console.log((0, _runner.options)());
  return buildParams;
}

function altBuild() {
  console.log((0, _runner.altOptions)());
  return altBuildParams;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the transpiled code?

Comment: I did Felix, but it got me just as curious as why it's not working as expected. I'll update the question with the transpiled code.

Comment: What is the reason behind the cyclic dependency you have between the two files ?

Comment: It's basically the organization of the code Ghassen. I sure can organize them in another way to avoid that, but I am curious on why I couldn't make it work like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In circular dependencies, while function *declarations* are immediately available for everything else there needs to be an initialisation order. This does not happen on a by-need basis (lazy), but is defined by the order of imports and then evaluates a complete module body.

In your case, depending on which file is required first, you either

1. get `defaultValue` inialised with the object
2. call `build()`, which gets the `options()` just fine but then refers to the uninitialised `buildParams`, and log the result
3. call `build()`, which gets the `altOptions()` just fine but then refers to the uninitialised `altBuildParams`, and log the result
4. get `buildParams` initialised with `options()` which gets the `defaultValue`
5. get `altBuildParams` initialised with `altOptions()`

or

1. get `buildParams` initialised with `options()` which refers to the uninitialised `defaultValue`
2. get `altBuildParams` initialised with `altOptions()`
3. get `defaultValue` inialised with the object
4. call `build()`, which gets the `options()` and uses `buildParams`, and log the result
5. call `build()`, which gets the `altOptions()` and uses `altBuildParams`, and log the result

In either case, you refer to a uninitialised variable, which would throw an exception in real ES6 but just ends up with `undefined` in the babel transpilation. You cannot make this work.

In general, only use function declarations in modules with circular dependencies and don't call anything in the module top scope (including variable initialisation). Make sure the code could at least work if put in one large file.